# NSData becomes nil after appending image data

Tags: ios, objective-c, utf-8, nsstring, nsdata

I am experiencing very strange behaviour from NSData. When I try to add image data, the NSData var is inexplicably set to nil:

```
NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic2"];
    NSLog(@"image data %@", UIImagePNGRepresentation(i));
    [postbody appendData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(i)];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSString *bodyString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:postbody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"body %@", bodyString);
```

Logging image data above shows that UIImagePNGRepresentation(i) is in fact returning data, but when body is logged, the log shows nil. Why would this be?

Comment: Is the NSData nil, or the NSString with NSUTF8 encoding nil?

Comment: Try logging the postbody description, vs converting to string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A PNG representation is not valid UTF-8. `postbody` contains 'arbitrary' data -- it cannot (reliably) be converted to a UTF-8 string (which is a structured, variable octet per character representation). So when you attempt to create a NSString from the data, it fails because the it finds the UTF-8 is malformed.

```
NSString *bodyString =
  [[NSString alloc] initWithData:postbody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                 ^^^^^^^^            ^^^^
```

Comment: @justicepenny you would need to convert it to another representation if you wanted to represent data as a string (e.g. Base-64). normally, you just use the data directly (e.g. `-setHTTPBody:`).